# Extract All Strings between a sequence of numbers

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm dealing with a regular expression in which I has string that has a series of numbers four numbers then name which repeat for multiples.

The text pattern is a series of 4 numbers, then a string. I would like to extract the string after the four numbers. The four numbers must appear before the string. In the example below, I do not want to extract "Not this one", but would like the strings after four numbers.

```
string_to_inspect <-"Not This One 4586 This one 8888 Another one 8955 PS109  8566 Last One"
```

My ideal extraction is a character vector that looks like:

```
"This one" "Another one" "PS109" "Last One"
```

I have tried

```
str_extract_all(pattern = "[0-9]{4}(.*?)", string = string_to_inspect)
```

And it returns a single string that include all the numbers

```
"4586 This one 8888 Another one 8955 PS109  8566 Last One"
```

I have tried various combinations but I know I must be missing something critical.

Comment: Your code returns `[1] "4586" "8888" "8955" "8566"`. 
What are the requirements here?

Comment: `strsplit(string_to_inspect, " \\d{4} ")`, maybe?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "This one" "Another one" "PS109" "Last One" character vector

Comment: That is an expected result. What are the requirements for the pattern? What should it match and why?

Comment: You may use `trimws(str_extract_all(string_to_inspect, "(?<=\\b[0-9]{4}\\s{1,100}).*?(?=\\b[0-9]{4}|$)")[[1]])`. Or `trimws(str_match_all(string_to_inspect, "\\b[0-9]{4}\\s+(.*?)(?=\\b[0-9]{4}|$)")[[1]][,2])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the string by four digits, remove the first one, and then trim the white space.

```
library(stringr)

str_trim(str_split(string_to_inspect, pattern = "\\s[0-9]{4}\\s")[[1]][-1])
# [1] "This one"    "Another one" "PS109"       "Last One"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Beware of cases when the value you need to extract contains 4 digits (e.g. if you have `PS1099` instead of `PS109`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please see my update. What if I add space before and after the four digit pattern? Would that help?

Comment: @www Since there are no specific requirements for the 4 digit context and given the sample input, yes, that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
strsplit(string_to_inspect, " [0-9]+ ")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want problems with strings mixed with numbers:

```
string_to_inspect <-"Not This One 4586 This one 8888 Another one 8955 PS109  8566 Last One"
str2insp <- strsplit(string_to_inspect, ' ')[[1]]
str2insp[!gsub('[[:digit:]]', '', str2insp) == '']
```

**outputs:**

`#[1] "Not"     "This"    "One"     "This"    "one"     "Another" "one"     "PS109"   "Last"    "One"`